# Polar Laplace equation on half disk: Neumann on flat surface and Dirichlet on the circle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

[image: schematic]

So we have an half disk as in the figure with boundaries $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$.

The variable of interest is $w(\rho,\phi)$ in polar coordinates (the temperature for the heat equation, for example) and must obey to:

$$\Delta_{\rho,\phi} w = 0 $$

with BC: $w(R,\phi) = w_0$ (Dirichlet BC on $\Gamma_1$) and $\boldsymbol{e_y} . \boldsymbol{\nabla} w \vert_{\phi = m \pi} = \frac{\cos \phi}{\rho} \partial_{\phi} w (\rho, {\phi = m \pi}) = f_0$ (Neumann BC on $\Gamma_2$), with $m = 0, 1$.

Because the problem is symmetric with respect to y axis and definite in $\rho = 0$ we have the general solution:

$$ w = A + \sum_{n=1} b_n \sin(n \phi) \rho^n $$

Let's apply the first BC, we obtain:

$$ w_0 = A + \sum_{n=1} b_n \sin(n \phi) R^n $$

Applying scalar product by $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(n \phi) d \phi$ we obtain $b_n$ in function of $A$:

$$ b_n = \frac{2 (w_0-A)}{n \pi R^n} \left[ 1 - (-1)^n \right] $$

Fine but we need $A$ now, let's apply the second BC:

$$ \sum_{n=1} n b_n \cos(n m \pi) \cos(m \pi) \rho^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1} n b_n (-1)^{m(n+1)} \rho^{n-1} = f_0 $$

How to reduce this last equation to find $A$ ?

The only idea I had was to scalar product by $\delta(\rho)$ (this certainly leads to an "incomplete" solution), delta function, that gave me:

$$b_1 = f_0$$

Then using the expression of $b_n$ I found $A = w_0 - \frac{\pi R f_0}{4}$, but I tried to plot it on Matlab but the partial derivative condition on flat surface $\Gamma_2$ is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to Laplace's equation that is regular at $\rho=0$ can be written as
$$
w(\rho,\phi)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\rho^n[a_n\cos(n\phi)+b_n\sin(n\phi)]. \tag{1}
$$
The boundary condition on $\Gamma_2$,
$$
\frac{\cos\phi}{\rho}\frac{\partial w(\rho,\phi)}{\partial\phi}\Bigg|_{\phi=0}=f_0, \tag{2}
$$
implies
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n b_n\rho^{n-1}=f_0. \tag{3}
$$
Equation $(3)$ can only be satisfied for arbitrary $\rho\in[0,R)$ if $b_1=f_0$ and $b_n=0$ for $n\geq 2$, hence $(1)$ simplifies to
$$
w(\rho,\phi)=a_0+f_0\rho\sin\phi+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\rho^n\cos(n\phi). \tag{4}
$$
Let's now apply the boundary condition on $\Gamma_1$, $w(R,\phi)=w_0$ for $0<\phi<\pi$, or
$$
a_0+f_0R\sin\phi+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nR^n\cos(n\phi)=w_0. \tag{5}
$$
Since the RHS of $(5)$ is symmetric under reflections over the $y$-axis, whereas $\cos(n\phi)$ is antisymmetric if $n$ is odd, we can conclude that $a_n=0$ for $n$ odd, so we can simplify $(5)$ to
$$
a_0+f_0R\sin\phi+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}R^{2n}\cos(2n\phi)=w_0. \tag{6}
$$
To determine $a_0$, we integrate both sides of $(6)$ over the interval $[0,\pi]$:
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\left[a_0+f_0R\sin\phi
+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}R^{2n}\cos(2n\phi)\right]d\phi=
\int_0^{\pi}w_0\,d\phi
$$
$$
\implies a_0\pi+2f_0R=\pi w_0 \implies a_0=w_0-\frac{2f_0R}{\pi}. \tag{7}
$$
Similarly, to determine $a_{2m}$ we multiply both sides of $(5)$ by $\cos(2m\phi)$ and integrate over $[0,\pi]$:
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\left[a_0+f_0R\sin\phi
+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}R^{2n}\cos(2n\phi)\right]\cos(2m\phi)\,d\phi=
\int_0^{\pi}w_0\cos(2m\phi)\,d\phi
$$
$$
\implies -\frac{2f_0R}{4m^2-1}+\frac{\pi}{2}a_{2m}R^{2m}=0
\implies a_{2m}=\frac{4f_0R^{1-2m}}{\pi(4m^2-1)}. \tag{8}
$$
Therefore, we can finally rewrite $(4)$ as
$$
w(\rho,\phi)=w_0-\frac{2f_0R}{\pi}+f_0\rho\sin\phi+\frac{4f_0R}{\pi}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\rho}{R}\right)^{2n}\,\frac{\cos(2n\phi)}{4n^2-1}. \tag{9}
$$