# Stationary temperature distribution in the hemisphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, heat-equation

Find stationary temperature distribution in the hemisphere of radius 1 in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with conditions $$\left. \frac{\partial T}{\partial n}\right|_{z=0}=Q=const,\;\;\; \left. T\right|_{side  surface}=0.$$

MY ATTEMPT:
Let $u$ be the solution. $v=u+Qz$. And continue it to the lower half-space to get even function.

Then $v$ is the solution to the problem
$$\left. \frac{\partial T}{\partial n}\right|_{z=0}=0,\;\;\; \left. T\right|_{side  surface, z\geq 0}=Qz, \left.T\right|_{side  surface, z\leq 0}=-Qz.$$
Then I rewrite it in polar coordinates $$Q|z|=Qr|cos(\theta)|.$$
Then I write standart decomposition into the linear combination of Legendre polynomials and find corresponding coeffitients.

Say please am I on the right path? There are terrible calculations that come to a dead end. Please help me.

Comment: You probably want to include mention of $\Delta T = 0$, the relationship between $T$ and $u$,  and other minor details as you see fit.

Comment: You can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612888/polar-laplace-equation-on-half-disk-neumann-on-flat-surface-and-dirichlet-on-th/4792834#4792834) a solution to the $2D$ version of this problem.