# A superposition problem (or not?)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have encountered a peculiar problem in my mathematical physics test which is nothing I have seen before.

> Solve $\Delta u(x) = 0$ inside a half-ball in $\mathbb R^3$, which is given by $|x| < R$, $x_3 > 0$, with the conditions $u|_{r=R} = 0$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3}|_{x_3=0} = q$ (a constant).

Separation of variables won't work here. I also thought I can separate the problem into two simpler ones:
$$(1)\;\; \Delta w = 0, x_3 > 0, \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_3}|_{x_3=0} = q \implies w = qx_3 = qr\cos\theta$$
$$(2)\;\; \Delta v = 0, v|_{|x|=R} = -qR\cos\theta, \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_3}|_{x_3=0} = 0, |x| < R, x_3 > 0.$$

If we can solve (2), the solution should be $u = w + v$. Are there any ways to solve (2)? It looks easier, I tried reflection from half-ball to whole ball, but my knowledge of reflections in physics is very weak.

Any other ways to solve this problem are also of course welcome.

Comment: Start by writing $\Delta u$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Aruralreader straightforward spherical coordinates do not give you anything in case of a half-ball

Comment: @Aruralreader I mean if you just write spherical coordinates and try separation of variables you arrive at a null solution.

Comment: This is a good problem, +1. I look forward to any and all progress.

Comment: You can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612888/polar-laplace-equation-on-half-disk-neumann-on-flat-surface-and-dirichlet-on-th/4792834#4792834) a solution to the $2D$ version of this problem.

Comment: Instead of solving $(2)$, you should solve 
$$
(2')\,\,\Delta v = 0\,\text{ for $|x|<R$},\quad v = -qR|\cos\theta\,|\,\text{ for $|x|=R.$}
$$
The result will satisfy the condition $\left.\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_3}\right|_{x_3=0}=0$.

Comment: @dnes: You might want to state the heating $q$ is constant, or at least that’s what I’m inferred from your argument on $w$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u$ be a solution to $\Delta u = 0$ in $\{|x| < R, x_3 > 0\}$ satisfying the conditions $u|_{|x|=R} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3}|_{x_3=0} = q$. Consider $U(x_1, x_2, x_3) = u(x_1, x_2, |x_3|)$ which is defined in the ball $\{|x| < R\}$.

Since
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} [u(x_1,x_2,|x_3|)] = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3}(x_1,x_2,|x_3|) \cdot (2H(x_3)-1),$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_3^2} [u(x_1,x_2,|x_3|)] = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_3^2} \cdot (2H(x_3)-1)^2 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3} \cdot 2\delta(x_3) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_3^2} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3}|_{x_3=0} 2\delta(x_3) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_3^2} + 2q\delta(x_3),$$
we have a new Dirichlet problem which is
$$\Delta U = \Delta u + 2q\delta(x_3) = 2q\delta(x_3);$$
$$U|_{|x|=R} = 0.$$

We are then, due to nature of $\delta(x_3)$, looking for a solution in the form
$$U(x) = qx_3H(x_3) + f(x),$$
where
$$\Delta f = 0, f|_{r=R} = -qx_3H(x_3) = -qR\cos\theta H(\cos\theta).$$

The problem for $f$ is standard and its solution has the form
$$f(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} A_k |x|^k P_k(\cos\theta),$$
where $P_k$ are the Legendre polynomials. For the boundary condition, putting $y = \cos\theta$ we have

$$\sum_{k \geq 0} A_k R^k P_k(y) = -q R y H(y).$$

The coefficients $A_k$ are computed using orthogonality $\int_{-1}^{1} dy P_k(y) P_m(y) = \delta_{km} \frac{2}{2m+1}:$

$$A_m = \frac{2m+1}{2R^m} \int_{0}^1 yP_m(y)dy.$$

$A_0 = \frac{1}{4}$, $A_1 = \frac{1}{2R}$. For further odd $m$ $A_m = 0$, while for even $m$ this is a lengthy computation with a lengthy answer. The computation can be done using $P_m(y) = \frac{1}{2^m m!}\frac{d^m}{dy^m} (y^2-1)^m$ and integration by parts. So the overall solution is

$$u = q|x|\cos\theta H(\cos\theta) + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2R}|x|\cos\theta + \sum_{k \geq 0} A_{2k} |x|^{2k} P_{2k}(\cos\theta)$$